# Quickly select contiguous group of files with the same extension in current panel view

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, far-manager

Far Manager has by now acquired many useful key combinations to do with file selection. The good old ones, like <kbd>Ins</kbd>, <kbd>Numpad +</kbd>, <kbd>Numpad -</kbd>, <kbd>Numpad *</kbd>  etc., I use a lot, but the ones I am especially fond of are <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad +</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad -</kbd>, which are to do with quickly selecting and deselecting all files in the current panel view that have the same extension as the file under the cursor.

What I am interested in is a shortcut for doing something very similar to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad +</kbd>, only the files selected need to be in the same contiguous group as shown in the panel. For instance, if the panel currently contained a file list like this:

```
  output20180605_744.ext
  output20180605_743.ext
  output20180605_742.ext
  mno.xyz
  def.log
  output20180604_741.ext
 >output20180604_740.ext<
  output20180604_739.ext
  output20180604_738.ext
  abc.cfg
  abc.exe
```

with the `>...<` marking the position of the file cursor, then pressing the key combination would select four files like this:

```
  output20180605_744.ext
  output20180605_743.ext
  output20180605_742.ext
  mno.xyz
  def.log
√ output20180605_741.ext
√>output20180605_740.ext<
√ output20180605_739.ext
√ output20180604_738.ext
  abc.cfg
  abc.exe
```

No such combination is mentioned in the built-in help, so my guess is it does not exist by default. But maybe there are existing plugins that introduce it. I have also heard of macros but I am a complete beginner with regard to them. Is there a way to quickly select a contiguous group of files with the same extension in Far Manager?

Comment: You need to write custom Macros using Lua. You may ask in forums for reference https://forum.farmanager.com/viewforum.php?f=26. Maybe you can record and then edit the macros to add your conditions (scan up and down for selection).

Comment: @anatolytechtonik: Thanks, that's what I'm thinking too. I'll eventually post my own solution once I've figured it out (unless someone posts a better one before me, of course).